# How to search throughout the first cell of lists, with each list being values in a dict?

Tags: python

I am working on a dictionary containing keys and values, with the keys being IDs and each value being a list. How could I check a condition like, "if there is 6 as the FIRST element of any list"?

```
dict_ = {0: [1, 2, 4, 1], 1: [3, 8, 4, 7], 2: [6, 2, 4, 2], 3: [5, 1, 3, 6]}

if 6 in dict_.values[0]():
    print("6 is in the first cell of one of the lists")
    return(True)
```

This looks like what I want to do but it's not the right syntax and gives me "TypeError object is not sub scriptable". I expect it to return True only if there is a 6 on the [0] of one of the lists.

Comment: Do you want it that any of the dictionary values starts with `6`?

Comment: `if any(value[0] == 6 for value in d.values() if value)`

Comment: Also, don't use `dict` as a name, you won't be able to use the built-in `dict` type as it will be hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in function [`any`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/any) for a one-liner:

```
any(val[0] == 6 for val in dict.values())
```

Add an `if val` at the end for extra safety, in case any of the lists are null or empty.

Answer (score 0):

Let's get the values of the `dict` first:

```
dict_ = {0: [1, 2, 4, 1], 1: [3, 8, 4, 7], 2: [6, 2, 4, 2], 3: [5, 1, 3, 6]}

for key, val in dict_.items():
    print(val)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[1, 2, 4, 1]
[3, 8, 4, 7]
[6, 2, 4, 2]
[5, 1, 3, 6]
```

Now to check if the values (list) has a `6` on the first index:

```
for key, val in dict_.items():  # for each key, val (list) in the dict
    if val[0] == 6:            # [0] for the first index of each list
          print("6 found at the first index in the list: ", val)
```

OUTPUT:

```
6 found at the first index in the list:  [6, 2, 4, 2]
```

Comment: i don't get people who downvote and don't explain why... thanks for the well-explained answer

Comment: I think he was probably jealous or something.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
dictionary = {0: [1, 2, 4, 1], 1: [3, 8, 4, 7], 2: [6, 2, 4, 2], 3: [5, 1, 3, 6]}

for key, val in dictionary.items():
    if val[0] == 6:
        print("6 is present at 1 st position :", key,":",val)
```

Output:

```
6 is present at 1 st position : 2 : [6, 2, 4, 2]
```

Comment: I iterated the dictionary using `items()` function of dictionary. We get key as a e.g -0 and val as a e.g - [1,2,4,1] . Then I check `0 th` element of each val (means list) is 6 or not. If condition true then print key and val

Comment: Since you're new to SO, it's good to put your clarification as an [edit to your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54420598/edit). Comments are ephemeral, they can be deleted at any time. While answers can help future users indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

First, *never* shadow a built-in: use `d` or `dict_` instead of `dict` as a variable name. Second, note that `dict.values()` returns a *view*, you can't apply `__getitem__` (or `[]`) on a view object, let alone a method which you haven't called via parentheses.

You can modify your function and use simple iteration:

```
d = {0: [1, 2, 4, 1], 1: [3, 8, 4, 7], 2: [6, 2, 4, 2], 3: [5, 1, 3, 6]}

def check_value(d, val, pos=0):
    for value in d.values():
        if value[pos] == val:
            return True
    return False

res = check_value(d, 6)  # True
```

You can also use `any` with a generator expression:

```
def check_value_any(d, val, pos=0):
    return any(value[pos] == val for value in d.values())
```

This is lazy, i.e. if the conditional is met at any point `any` returns `True` and the function returns `True`. However, this may be less efficient as generators carry additional overhead.

Comment: Doesn't `d.values()` return a generator (in Python 3.x) anyway?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog, No, it returns a "view". Iterating a "view" is efficient, it doesn't require a new frame each iteration as per a generator. There's no `yield` when you iterate `d.values()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean but I'll try to answer you.

First of all, you iterate through dictionary like this:

```
for key, values in d.items():
```

you can also use `d.keys()` or `d.values()`, depending on what you need.

Now, if you need to see if `6` is on the first position in any list in dictionary, you can do it like this:

```
for key, value in d.items():
  if value[0] == 6:
    return True
```

If you want to see if number 6 appears in the first list (of the first key), you can do that with:

```
for value in list(d.keys())[0]:
  if value == 6:
    return True
```